# Android write to file and view file's content in simple text editor

Tags: java, android, file

I was able to successfully write to the file. The files were present in the file manager through DDMS. But for debugging purposes, how can we open those files? Suppose one file is a simple .txt file, how can I view its contents in the notepad (I'm on windows)? How can I get to this file in the windows explorer?

Comment: Yes below are some great answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **DDMS -> file manager -> click on Pull a file from device** then save this file in your computer

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the file may go into data -> data -> your package.

Answer (score 1):

Use command

```
adb pull /sdcard/foo.txt D:/foo.txt
```

"sdcard/foo.txt" is your file path and "D:/foo.txt" means pull the "foo.txt" to your Windows "D:/foo.txt"， then you can view it using Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use "adb shell cat /path/to/your/file"?
If you really want the file, you can also use "adb pull" to copy it to your local file system.